# Freeze header or footer lines in OS X Ventura ANSI terminal and retain scrollbar functionality

Tags: bash, scrollbar, ansi-escape

I wish to programmatically (ANSI codes or platform-specific codes, doesn't matter) make a terminal screen freeze 1 or 2 rows either at the top or the bottom of the screen while new material written to the screen scrolls as normal -- including making use of the scrollbar to go back to much older material.  The setup is very similar to something like this:

```
clear screen
print header line 1
print header line 2
set scrolling region to lines 3 to last line
tail -f some_file
```

This "almost" works but using the standard ANSI sequence for scroll region lock `ESC[n;mr` inhibits the scrollbar functionality.  New material coming in the `tail -f` pushes the old material off the top leaving the headers in place (correct!) but the old material is lost; the scrollbar scrollback does not get the old material.

I am open to freezing a footer or even getting exotic and programmatically splitting the pane (terminal, OS X).  It does not need to be portable.  The basic requirement is the header lines stay put and other material flows into the scrollbar scrollback memory.

Alternately, if a full-fledged program kind of like `tail++` already does this, I am willing to look at that too although I currently I have full programmatic control over the header so as `tail -f` material comes in, I can write it to the scroll region AND also update, say, a timestamp in the header, then return the cursor to the "waiting" position.

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood; do you get the required outcome if you type `head -2 header` then press "cmd+d", then type `tail -f file`?

Comment: That is half the battle.    It solves the scrolling issue but I have no programmatic control over the header, not to mention `cmd+d` does a simply splits the window into 2 equal size panes, not an unequal split.

Comment: That makes sense but I'm not sure on how to 'tick all those boxes', sorry. I've used multitail (https://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/manual.html) before, but I don't know if it can provide that functionality; perhaps it's worth a look if nobody else has an answer